# Import Executable JAR in TALEND Open Studio- Run with par

Tags: java, executable-jar, talend

I'm trying to import an Executable JAR into Talend project.
This Executable JAR needs 1 parameter to run:my goal is to call this via tJava or tJavaFlex by passing this param.
Is there any way to do this?
Already tried to use tLoadLibrary, also to create a Routine without success.

Comment: is there any error, are able to access that jar class and functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a routine in the code section. Save it.
2. Right click on the routine to edit the routine libraries.  Locate and add your jar.
3. Edit the dependecies of your job and add the created routine.
4. Add the required import in a tJava component.
5. You should be able to use the library in the tJava from now

That's the way I managed to use an external jar.